# input-textarea width is too large

Tags: html, css

i've a problem and this is the wrong example.

 http://jsfiddle.net/kHSNC/1/ 
I want to fix the input width for put it equal to the submit button without using the pixel dimension. I would use the .span8 class

```
.span8 {width: 500px;}
```

Thanks

Comment: **and this is the wrong example.** Is your Fiddle wrong or you mean to say the code is wrong?

Comment: Pasting links to JSFiddle without a copy of the code sample here is frowned upon. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/126000#126000)

Comment: that is my code and it's wrong because the area is too large than the .span8 class

Comment: What is your need , i cant understand what you are asking

Comment: Check your paddings dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kHSNC/4/)**

Just set the width of `input` and `textarea` in pixels, not percentage:

```
.contact-form input { width: 470px; }
.contact-form textarea { resize: vertical; width: 470px; }
```

---

Setting `padding` to an element, increase the calculated width, so when you have something like this:

```
.parent { width: 500px; }
.parent .child { width: 100%; padding: 15px; }
```

The calculated width of child, will be `530px`.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that you can change this behavior https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @xec Unfortunately, the `box-sizing` property doesn't support completely by browsers, see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

Comment: Completely aware. There is a compatibility list at the link I posted too, but the lack of support is negligible (IE7 is dead) also check out http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: @xec Thanks for the link. The informations was great :)

Comment: thanks to both of you for the fix, the links and the support